# PHP objects with count

Tags: php, json, class, parsing

How can i do something like this?

```
class record
{
    public $count;
}

$i = 0;
foreach($entry as $item) {
    $i++;
    $record$i = new record();
        $record$i->count = $item['count'];
        print $page$i;
}
```

Specifically, this part here is giving me errors.

```
$record$i = new record();
```

Note: the loop works fine if i just do `print $item['count']`

The error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: It might be helpful if you included the error message in your question.

Comment: included..though i suspect i am doing a lot wrong, which is why i think its more of a not knowing php error haha

Comment: `$record$i` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @onetrickpony can you explain what the {} does?

Comment: @vascowhite yes i think that's the error not sure how to do correctly though

Comment: @Lemonio You could always read the manual.

Comment: You must rethink the whole thing again. Why would you need such solution?

Comment: Why are you not just using an array? `$records[0]`, `$records[1]` etc.

Comment: @Tomás are there any much better ways to do this? i'm certainly no php expert, so not sure how this breaks best practices

Comment: @vascowhite which section of the manual would i read for this issue? (apart from reading the entire manual in a sitting)

Comment: @Lemonio Well, judging by your code above and your comments [this would be a good place to start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php).

Comment: @vascowhite haha ok will do. i probably won't have to write more than say 30 lines of php for a super basic task so might not be worth it at this point

Comment: @Lemonio Maybe if you explain what it is you are trying to achieve you'll get an answer that gives you a better method. Edit an explanation of your goal into your question and see if you get any better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see http://3v4l.org/lB4sR

```
${'record'.$i};
```

you can create a string that holds a varname and use it as a variable later - see the example

<sub>**Edit: but like @h2ooooooo sais in the comment to your question: use an array.</sub>

Comment: thank you this fixed the error! but as for using an array, suppose i added each entry to an array, how i would access each variable?

Answer (score 1):

Hope is that what you asking, but I do not understand why to use such bad methods to count...

```
class record
{
    static $countq = 0;
    public function count(){
       self::$countq++;

    }
}
$entry = array(1, 4, 6, 7);

$obj = new record();
foreach($entry as $item) {
         $obj->count();    
}

echo record::$countq;
```